# android sms receive and reply without user interface

Tags: java, android

i want to build a android application that first received a message from any number and after 
receive message i want hold the message string  and number in the variables and then reply message adding some extra string in message to same no automatically without user interface.
i am new in android so please help me.

only i have receiving message code....plese give me solution for rest of code.
thank you

My brodcost reciver class
       package com.example.broadcastreceiver;

```
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.telephony.SmsManager;
   import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.Toast;


   public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

    SmsMessage currentMessage =  SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();


                System.out.println(phoneNumber);
                System.out.println(currentMessage);

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
          } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
   }


     }
```

my main activity

```
     package com.example.broadcastreceiver;

    import com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.R;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;


   public class BroadcastNewSms extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.androidexample_broadcast_newsms);
    Ssystem.out.println("")

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you now should send your message from your broadcast, you should:

```
PendingIntent sentIntent; // can be null
PendingIntent deliveryIntent;  // can be null
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

you might consider putting it into `IntentService`, I am not sure how long execution of sendTextMessage takes, and broadcasts should not do any heavy computations/processing. Also putting this code into `IntentService`, will prevent android from killing your app, this is important because you want this to work in background and android might create your app just to make it receive broadcast, and after onReceive ends it might kill your app, Service will prolong your app life.